# MFMailComposeViewController attachment added and working fine with real device but in Test Flight its not comming with attachment how can i test it?

Tags: ios, swift

In my app i have save my some log starng to a Text File and i want to mail it .Is working with real device development mode. but when i give build to testFlight in that time its not comming attachement ?

here is my Code :

```
    func sentEmail(path: String, fileName: String, fileExtension: String, reciverEmail:String, messageBody: String, emailSubject: String) {
        
 
        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail(){
            
            let mailComposer = MFMailComposeViewController()
            mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self
            mailComposer.setSubject(emailSubject)
            mailComposer.setMessageBody(messageBody, isHTML: false)
            let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
            let fileManager = FileManager.default
            if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: path) {
                if let fileData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path) {
                    mailComposer.addAttachmentData(fileData as Data, mimeType: "txt/rtf", fileName: "Med-Audit-Log-File")
                }
            } else {
                print("FILE NOT AVAILABLE")
            }
            
            self.present(mailComposer, animated: true, completion: nil)
            
        }

    }
```

How i constructed path :

```
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        if let documentsURL = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
            let auditTextFilePath = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("Med-Audit-Log-File.txt").path
            
            self.sentEmail(path: auditTextFilePath, fileName: "LogFile", fileExtension: "txt", reciverEmail: "ekramramu@gmail.com", messageBody: "Log file of MED-AUDIT Scoring App ", emailSubject: "MED-AUDIT Scoring App Log file")
          
            if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: auditTextFilePath) {
               print("NO Such a File here in document directory")
            }
            
            
        }
```

Delegete Method:

```
 
    func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
       
        switch result.rawValue {
            case MFMailComposeResult.cancelled.rawValue:
                print("Mail cancelled")
                self.showSingleBtnAlert(title: "Attention", message: "Email have been cancel", okButtonTitle: "Ok")
            case MFMailComposeResult.saved.rawValue:
                self.showSingleBtnAlert(title: "Success", message: "Email has been Saved.", okButtonTitle: "Ok")
                print("Mail saved")
            case MFMailComposeResult.sent.rawValue:
                self.showSingleBtnAlert(title: "Attention", message: "Email has been Sent", okButtonTitle: "Ok")
                print("Mail sent")
            case MFMailComposeResult.failed.rawValue:
                self.showSingleBtnAlert(title: "Attention", message: "Email has been failed", okButtonTitle: "Ok")
            default:
                break
            }
  
    }

``
```

Comment: is there any real device mode in test flight ??

Comment: Yes its running real device

Comment: but still same @matt

Comment: is it need to take any permission for accessing document directory ?

Comment: Show how the file path is constructed.

Comment: i m upding my question with file path

Comment: @DavidH updated my Question with Construct URL. and now i check its working on when build configuration is "Debug' but not working when its Release mode. and in release mode i cant open file ..Error is "This file "X" can't  Open "